# Get attribute value behaviour with `Accept: */*` header

Tags: fiware-orion

We have a doubt about the `/v2/entities/{entityId}/attrs/{attrName}/value` operation behaviour, if we use the  `Accept: */*` header, the Context Broker tries to return an unsupported format.

```
curl -v orion:1026/v2/entities/Bcn-Welt/attrs/humidity/value
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 172.17.0.13...
* Connected to orion (172.17.0.13) port 1026 (#0)
> GET /v2/entities/Bcn-Welt/attrs/humidity/value HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: orion:1026
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 73
< Content-Type: application/json
< Fiware-Correlator: d289fd9e-2329-11e6-88cc-0242ac11000d
< Date: Thu, 26 May 2016 10:08:41 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host orion left intact
{"error":"NotAcceptable","description":"accepted MIME types: text/plain"}
```

We need to explicitly accept the `text/plain` format:

```
curl -v orion:1026/v2/entities/Bcn-Welt/attrs/humidity/value --header "Accept: text/plain"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 172.17.0.13...
* Connected to orion (172.17.0.13) port 1026 (#0)
> GET /v2/entities/Bcn-Welt/attrs/humidity/value HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: orion:1026
> Accept: text/plain
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 9
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Fiware-Correlator: 70b2a3f8-232b-11e6-a36a-0242ac11000d
< Date: Thu, 26 May 2016 10:20:16 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host orion left intact
```

If we provided a list of accepted formats or even a not supported format (except JSON), the application returns the value.

```
curl -v orion:1026/v2/entities/Bcn-Welt/attrs/humidity/value --header "Accept: audio/*"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 172.17.0.13...
* Connected to orion (172.17.0.13) port 1026 (#0)
> GET /v2/entities/Bcn-Welt/attrs/humidity/value HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: orion:1026
> Accept: audio/*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 9
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Fiware-Correlator: a216e33c-232b-11e6-83f3-0242ac11000d
< Date: Thu, 26 May 2016 10:21:39 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host orion left intact
60.000000
```

If we provide a JSON format in the accepted list, the request fails:

```
curl -v orion:1026/v2/entities/Bcn-Welt/attrs/humidity/value --header "Accept: text/plain" --header "Accept: application/json"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 172.17.0.13...
* Connected to orion (172.17.0.13) port 1026 (#0)
> GET /v2/entities/Bcn-Welt/attrs/humidity/value HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: orion:1026
> Accept: text/plain
> Accept: application/json
> 
< HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 73
< Content-Type: application/json
< Fiware-Correlator: 375fb1a8-232c-11e6-a21e-0242ac11000d
< Date: Thu, 26 May 2016 10:25:49 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host orion left intact
{"error":"NotAcceptable","description":"accepted MIME types: text/plain"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case by case:

- In the first case, what is happening is that Orion (as in version 1.1 and before) *first* selects the MIME type, *then* considers if the attribute type fits in it or not. Using `Accept: */*` there is a tie between application/json and text/plain and Orion choses application/json as winner. Then, given that the value of the attribute is of text nature, an error is returned.
- The second case is probably a bug. We have created [an issue at github](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2208) about it.
- The third case is similar to the first one. There is a tie between text/plain and application/json. Orion chose the second one. Then, when it evaluates the attribute value it realizes that it doesn't match application/json MIME type and return an error.

In fact, the procedure implements in case 1 or 3 is not the best one. The attribute type should be evaluated *before* chosing the MIME type among all the possible options in the `Accept` header. I mean, to implement what is described [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1849):

> - if attribute value is an array or object and Accept header contains application/json or text/plain: return the value as a JSON with a response type of application/json or text/plain (whichever is the first in Accept header).
> - if attribute value is a string, number, null or boolean:
>
>   - if Accept header contains text/plain return the value as text
>   - else return a HTTP error "406 Not Acceptable: accepted MIME types: text/plain"

That procedure will be implemented at Orion in a next version.

**EDIT:** the new procedure has been implemented in Orion 1.3.0.

Comment: Regarding case 3, I'm not fully sure that Orion supports multi-header for Accept (an issue has been created about that: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2209). It supports comma-separate lists, i.e. `Accept: text/plain, application/json`. Maybe what is happening is that only the last Accept header (application/json) is being considered, so this case would be fully equivalent to case 1.

Comment: Answer text edited, to include information about the Orion version that will implement the new procedure (Orion 1.3.0, to be released by the end of July or August).